# Mapping a variable to the state in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having a problem mapping a certain value to the state.For example, using this json var on my state (its an example only, doesnt need to make sense the json variable):

```
this.state={
 person:
            {
                nose:'',
                legs:{
                    knees:'',
                    foot:{
                        finger:'',
                        nail:''
                    }
                }
            }
   }
```

What I want to to is to create this 'person' on my frontend, by user input, and the send it to my backend,but Im having a problem.

Imagine that I want to change the person.nose atribute of my state variable.

The user writes the information by using this input field:

```
<input name={props.name} onChange={handleChange} type="text" className="form-control" />
```

And this is the call that I made to that same component:

```
       <TextInput name="nose" onChange={this.handleChange} />
```

When executing the handleChange method,I cant update the variable,its always empty, I have tried using on the name field on my textInput "name","this.state.person.nose" but nothing happened, its always empty.

Here is my handleChange method:

```
 handleChange(evt) {
    this.setState({ [evt.target.name]: evt.target.value });
}
```

NEW EDIT:

So, now Im having this problem.This is a more realistic json object than the first one:

```
{
            name: '',
            iaobjectfactory: {
                institution: '',
                parameter: [{
                    value: '',
                    classtype: ''
                }],
                name: '',
                usedefaultinstitution: '',
                methodname: ''
            },
            ieventhandlerclass: ''
        }
```

This is the output that my frontend should give me, but this is what the most recent solution returned me:

```
{
"name":"d",
"iaobjectfactory":{
    "institution":"",
    "parameter":[
        {
        "value":"",
        "classtype":""
        }
        ],
    "name":"",
    "usedefaultinstitution":"",
    "methodname":""},
"ieventhandlerclass":"d",
"institution":"d",
"methodname":"d",
"usedefaultinstitution":"d"
```

}

The values that should be on the iaobjectfactory are outside of it,I dont know why, I used this:

```
 handleChange(evt) {
    const { name, value } = evt.target;

    // use functional state
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
        // update the value in eventType object
        eventType: {
            // keep all the other key-value pairs
            ...prevState.eventType,
            // update the eventType value

            [name]: value
        }
    }))
```

EDIT 2:

This is the json output now.

```
{
 "name":"",
 "iaobjectfactory":{
 "institution":"bb",
 "parameter":[
     {"value":"",
     "classtype":""
     }],
 "name":"bb",
 "usedefaultinstitution":"bb",
 "methodname":"bb",
 "ieventhandlerclass":"aa"},
"ieventhandlerclass":""}
```

Problems:The first name is not reading and the ieventhandlerclass is inside the iaobjectfactory and it shouldnt

Comment: So you have multiple inputs for each parent attribute of the object?
An input for nose and legs?

Answer (score 1):

Problem with your code is, it will create a new variable `nose` in state and assign the value to that key. you can access the input value using `this.state.nose`.

Updating nested state is not that easy, you have to take care about all the other key-value pairs. In your case `nose` will be accessible by `this.state.person.nose`, so you need to update `person.nose` value not `nose` value.

You need to write it like this:

```
this.handleChange(evt) {
    const { name, value } = evt.target;

    // use functional state
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
        // update the value in person object
        person: {
            // keep all the other key-value pairs
            ...prevState.person,
            // update the person value
            [name]: value
        }
    }))
}
```

What it will do is, it will keep all the key-value pairs as it is and only update the `person.nose` value.

**Update:**

You are trying to update value of `person.iaobjectfactory.name` not `person.name`, so you need to keep all the key-values of `person.iaobjectfactory` and update only one at a time, like this:

```
handleChange(evt) {
  const { name, value } = evt.target;

  // use functional state
  this.setState((prevState) => ({
    // update the value in eventType object
    eventType: {

      // keep all the other key-value pairs of eventType
      ...prevState.eventType,

      // object which you want to update
      iaobjectfactory: {

        // keep all the other key-value pairs of iaobjectfactory
        ...prevState.eventType.iaobjectfactory,

        // update
        [name]: value
      }
    }
  }))
}
```

Comment: Assuming in my case that for example a person has skin but a leg has skin as well, is there a problem to have two variable with the same name on it?

Comment: no, you can use the same key any number of times but at the different level, i mean in `person.skin, person.leg.skin or person.legs.foot.skin`. duplicates keys are not possible at the same level.

Comment: what key of `iaobjectfactory` you are trying to update?

Comment: Its still bugy,updated question @Mayank Shukla.And thanks for all be help btw!

Comment: the method i have shared is not a common one to update any value at any level, its very specific to that nested case. it will be very complex to handle all key-value update (in case of nested json) by a single function.